# Finding similar elements of an array within a value of a hash in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have the following hash:

```
hash = {"One" => [1,2,3,4], "Two" => [1,5,6,7], "Three" => [1,8,9,10]}
```

And a conditional statement that puts a string if the first element of every array in the hash begins with 1.

```
if hash.values.all?{|array| array[0] == 1}
  puts "Hello World"
end
```

Is there a way to alter the inputted block to check if all combinations of the values that share the same index also share the same value?

Example:

```
hash = {"One" => [4,1,3,11], "Two" => [14,1,6,7], "Three" => [12,1,9,10]}

if hash.values.all?{|array| array[0 or 1 or 2 or 3] == 1} (I know this is not valid Ruby code)
  puts "Hello World"
end
```

Update:

hash["One"], hash["Two"] and hash["Three"] all currently contain arrays as their values. Within their arrays, the element 1 is in the each of their [1] index position. I need to run a conditional statement where if an element, such as 1, is in the same index position of multiple arrays, that are each nested as values of keys within a hash, it puts a string. Please note the element must be in each array and at the same index position for it to pass true.

```
hash = {"One" => [1,2,3,4], "Two" => [1,5,6,7], "Three" => [1,8,9,10]} # => True, 1 is in the [0] position for each array

hash = {"One" => [1,2,3,4], "Two" => [15,5,6,7], "Three" => [1,8,9,10]} # => Fail, 1 doesn't exist in the second array

hash = {"One" => [1,2,3,4], "Two" => [4,1,6,7], "Three" => [1,8,9,10]} # => Fail, 1 exists in the [0] position of the first and third array but [1] in the second array

hash = {"One" => [4,1,3,4], "Two" => [9,1,6,7], "Three" => [55,1,9,10]} # => True, 1 is in the [1] position for each array
```

Comment: You mean to check if all the *values* in the array are the same (not the *indices*)? For example, `[4,4,4,4]`? If so, you'd have to use an embedded check, like `hash.values.all? { |array| array.all? {|x| x == 4 } }`

Comment: No, if array1 = [1,2,3] and array2 = [5,2,10], I need to check that array1[1] is that same as array2[1]...but under the circumstances listed above.

Comment: Could you please cite a complete example in your problem statement to make this clear? Right now it's not clear what you're after. Your example as it stands uses an invalid construct for the context, `array[0..5]` which is itself an array consisting of the elements indexed 0 through 5 in `array` which can't possibly be equal to `1`. It would be clearer if you said what you want it to mean.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed! Thanks so much, please make it an answer so I can give you the best answer :)

Comment: I still don't understand the question. Can you add a few example hashes and give the expected or desired output (just `true` or `false`?) for each, together with "why" if appropriate? If it is not necessary that all arrays (values) be the same size, please reflect that in your examples.

Comment: @Lasonic Is the second half of my answer correctly giving you what you need, then?

Comment: Your examples make it clear. I think you could have expressed the question quite simply and unambiguously: "I am given a hash whose values are all arrays of the same size. I would like to determine if there is at least one index `i` such that `a[i] = 1` for all the arrays `a`". Is that correct? That the arrays are values in a hash is really not relevant, because you don't use the keys and know how to extract the values into an array (`h.values`). You could have just said you have an array of arrays of equal size, and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a fun way to ensure that all your arrays have at least one slot with the same value across the slot:

```
hash = {"One" => [4,1,3,11], "Two" => [14,1,6,7], "Three" => [12,1,9,10]}
if hash.values.transpose.map(&:uniq).any?{ |a| a.length==1 }
  # at least one of the 'slots' has all the same value
end
```

To be clear, this code will match either of:

```
a = { one:[8,9,6], two:[1,9,2], three:[0,9,0] }
b = { one:[7,7,7], two:[6,6,7], three:[4,3,7] }
```

…because in both cases the there is one 'slot' that has the same value in all arrays. (In `a` the second slots are all `9`, in `b` the third slots are all `7`.)

It would not match:

```
c = { one:[1,1,1], two:[2,2,2], three:[3,3,3] }
```

because though each array has the same values, the values in each corresponding slot are all unique, i.e. `[1,2,3]` across each index.

---

If, alternatively, the values must not only be the same, but be the value of that index—i.e. `0` for the first index, `1` for the second, and so on—then you could do:

```
if hash.values.transpose.map(&:uniq).select.with_index{ |a,i| a.length==1 && a.first==i }.first
  # at least one of the 'slots' is consistently filled with
  # a value that is the index of the slot
end
```

In this case none of `a`, `b`, or `c` would match, but this would:

```
d = { one:[3,4,2,6], two:[8,1,2,2], three:[9,6,2,4] }
```

…because the third slot (index #2) always has a `2` in it.

A similar (arguably more understandable) technique would be:

```
if hash.values.transpose.to_enum(:any?).with_index{ |a,i| a.all?{ |n| n==i } }
  # yay!
end
```

---

### Explanation

As requested, let's understand these answers by looking at the calls and the interim values:

#### Solution #1 - any slot has all the same value (any value)

```
hash = {"One" => [4,1,3,11], "Two" => [14,1,6,7], "Three" => [12,1,9,10]}

# Get an array of just the value parts of the hash
hash.values   
#=> [ [4,1,3,11], [14,1,6,7], [12,1,9,10] ]

# 'Rotate' the array of arrays, swapping 'rows' and 'columns'
hash.values.transpose  
#=> [ [4,14,12], [1,1,1], [3,6,9], [11,7,10] ] 

# Convert each of the new arrays to the set of distinct values in the array
# Equivalent to hash.values.transpose.map{ |a| a.uniq }
hash.values.transpose.map(&:uniq)
#=> [ [4,14,12], [1], [3,6,9], [11,7,10] ] 

# Test to see if any of these arrays has only one value in it
# i.e. If the array started out with all the same values
hash.values.transpose.map(&:uniq).any?{ |a| a.length==1 }
#=> true    (the second array-of-unique-values has only one element)
```

#### Solution 2a: Any slot has all the values at that index

We've already covered `hash.values.transpose.map(&:uniq)` above, so we'll pick up from there:

```
slot_values = hash.values.transpose.map(&:uniq)

# Create an Enumerator that selects items
# Normally select would take a block and return the matching values;
# When called without a block it gives you a 'delayed' form, the Enumerator
slot_values.select
#=> #<Enumerator: [[4,14,12],[1,1,1],[3,6,9],[11,7,10]]:any?>

# Add an index to the values during enumeration
slot_values.select.with_index
#=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator: [[4,14,12],[1,1,1],[3,6,9],[11,7,10]]:any?>:with_index>

# Invoke the enumerator, getting passed an array and the index
# Choose to select the array only if it has one element,
# and that element is the same value as the current index
slot_values.select.with_index{ |a,i| a.length==1 && a.first==i }
#=> [[1]]

# `.first` will return `nil` if the select returned no results,
# or the first array if there was at least one result.
# Because `nil` is considered "non-truthy", but an array is "truthy"
# We can use this as the condition for our if statement:
if slot_values.select.with_index{ |a,i| a.length==1 && a.first==i }.first
#=> …we enter the if statement because `.first` returns `[1]`…
```

#### Solution 2b: Any slot has all the values at that index

We'll start with the transposed values:

```
slotvals = hash.values.transpose
#=> [ [4,14,12], [1,1,1], [3,6,9], [11,7,10] ] 

# Create an Enumerator (delayed evaluation) of the `any?` method
slotvals.to_enum(:any?)
#=> #<Enumerator: [[4,14,12],[1,1,1],[3,6,9],[11,7,10]]:any?>

# Add an index to the values that will be yielded to the enumerator
slotvals.to_enum(:any?).with_index
#=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator: [[4,14,12],[1,1,1],[3,6,9],[11,7,10]]:any?>:with_index>

# Invoke the enumerator, getting passed the array of slot values and the slot index
# For each array/index see if every value of the array equals the slot index
slotvals.to_enum(:any?).with_index{ |a,i| a.all?{ |n| n==i } }
#=> true  (bc the second array was all 1 values, which matched the array's index)
```

For more details on enumerators, read the [documentation on `Enumerator`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Enumerator.html).

Comment: You could simplify your last one a bit by replacing `select` with `any?` and dropping `.first`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I had thought I could, too, but `.any?` without a block just returns `true` in Ruby 2.0

Comment: That's good to know. At least I've maintained my perfect record of being wrong every time I don't test.

Comment: @CarySwoveland LOL :) FWIW I have discovered that `.to_enum(:any?).with_index` works as we'd both hoped for.

Comment: I wasn't aware the `to_enum` could take an argument. That's good to know. Also, I like your use of `all?`. `each_with_index.any?` in place of `.to_enum(:any?).with_index`? (I did make one test.)

Comment: @Phrogz Your answer does what I'm looking for but quite frankly is way over my head (as I am fairly new to the language). Can you please explain the .transpose.to_enum(:any?) part of your solution?

Comment: @Lasonic I've added explanation to the bottom of my answer. (It's still not clear to me if my solution #1 or #2 is what you needed. The first example at the end of your question seems at odd with your description. Further, your examples all show `1` as the value that matches, so it's not clear if any value is valid, or if the values must all be a `1`.)